# FET Default on, Turn off with Optocoupler

Tags: power-supply, transistors, switches, opto-isolator, fet

I am relatively new to electronics and having trouble designing a circuit for a redundant power supply, which I would like to switch to battery if the voltage regulator turns off. This will be approximately 40V, and high current (60A). I

I have an idea that the FET will be pulled up using the battery source which will default on. Then, I would like to use an optocoupler to turn it off. I have designed a voltage regulator which has 9V auxiliary power out under normal conditions, which I would like to transmit via the optocoupler.

The trouble I am having is how to use the the optocoupler signal to override its pull up voltage.

Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: If you are switching 60A at 40V a relay is probably a better choice, sadly. A FET across the contacts to prevent arcing only at open and close can help. At say 10 milliOhms I^2R loss is 60^2 x 0.01 = 36 Watts. **IF** you can get FET genuine Rdson down to 2 milliOhms it's only 7 Watts. Still need heatsink. FET can be dome but takes care. ||. To turn hi side P channel FET on (source = +40V, drain = load output. Gate has resistor to ground AND a say 12V zener gate to v+ to stop VGS being exceeded. The opto connects gate to V+ to turn off FET when opto is on.

Comment: Hi Russell,, Thanks for you're reply. I will try your suggested solution. I would rather have an FET due to the quicker switching speed. I have found the IRFB7530PbF which has a RDs max of 2 mohms. I appreciate the need for a heatsink, can perhaps use two in parallel to spread the heat?

Comment: @Nour. If using FET / MOSFET be sure to insert a 100 ohm 1/4 watt resistor right at the gate of the MOSFET. This keeps them from self-oscillating, of which they are prone to do.

Comment: Nour - Excellent FET, good price, OK if heat sunk properly. **BUT NOTE** that is an N Channel FET which will switch OK BUT needs either to be in negative lead (ground) with voltages positive / reversed in above example OR on high side with drain to V+, source to load and with gate driven ABOVE V+. || P Channel FETS tend to have higher Rdson at same $ or more $ wity same Rdson. [datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfs7530pbf.pdf) and [pricing](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?keywords=IRFB7530PbF)